# Creating a Complex Loop

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm printing a couple hundred cities being pulled from an API. 
When printing I need to print the name of the city and I need to print a nmber from 0 to 50.  Once I reach 50, the next record should start at 0.  In addition to the first number I need to also provide a new set number for each set of  50.  Once 50 is completed, set 2 begins and so on.

printed, it should look something like below:

```
Processing Record 0 of Set 1 | 0    bathsheba
Name: 0, dtype: object 
Processing Record 1 of Set 1 | 0    upernavik
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Any ideas for some loops here?

Comment: what's the response from the API, if it's of type JSON (dictionaries) then `for` loops would work. again it depends on what the API looks like, maybe post that as well...

Answer (score 0):

Index all of the cities from zero onwards. Your record number is just the index modulo 50. The set is index / 50 + 1. `divmod` already does this for you. Using the new "f" string syntax you can

```
for i, city in enumerate(cities):
    zero_based_set, record = divmod(i, 50)
    print(f"Processing Record {record} of Set {zero_based_set+1} | 0    {city}")
```